# Polynomial knots in R

Tags: r, polynomial-math

This question is about a possible way to graphically represent knot polynomials as given by expressions [here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/23/stemkoski/knots/page4.html) and [here](http://www.mtholyoke.edu/~adurfee/reu/04/brown.pdf) in R.

Unfortunately I didn`t get very far since my math knowledge is not so good. This is what I have tried

```
phi <- seq(-30, 30, len=1001) 
fx <- phi^5 - 28*phi  #these are the polynomials from the website above
fy <- phi^7 - 32*phi^3
```

which gives, when using plot(fx,fy)
[image: r plot of the above function]

and I guess it should have given the figure-eight-knot. I can find zeroes of the above functions over the specified interval, and it all seems ok,since both functions have pairs of very similar zero values as can be seen in the knot diagram. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct. You just need to zoom in:

```
phi <- seq(-2.6, 2.6, len=1e5) 
fx <- phi^5 - 28*phi  
fy <- phi^7 - 32*phi^3

plot(fx, fy, type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the OP should change his question to " how do I find distinct values of `phi` for which the pairs `(fx1,fy1), (fx2,fy2)` are identical?  Once those are found, it's simple to select the "pan and zoom" parameters for the graph.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I like this quote from the paper the OP linked to: "However, we decide to calculate the t-values that yield the double points by using a computer". And they don't explain how to do that.

Comment: Carl is right, the problem with this is that pan and zoom parameters differ for different pairs of polynomials that define different knots. The question is how to find universal zoom parameters or a possible procedure?

Comment: @IanStuart  well, if you find the local collection of solution pairs `fx_n, fy_n` , where ,e.g., the picture  Roland posted has 4 such pairs, then set your axes to `xrange=max(fx[1:4])-min(fx[1:4]); xlim= c(min(fx[1:4])-xrange*.1,max(fx(1:4])+xrange*.1)` . I picked 10% "overage" here.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
phi <- seq(-3, 3, len=1001) 
fx <- phi^5 - 28*phi  
fy <- phi^7 - 32*phi^3
plot(fx,fy,xlim=c(-50,50),ylim=c(-150,150))
```

You have to adjust the limits of your axis. HF